# Running .exe located in specific folder from java program and read its output

Tags: java

Im trying to run Yolo detector from a java GUI i wrote. I can start the detector using windows cmd like so:

```
cd <pathToYolo> \\ In my case named :C:\\AI\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64
darknet.exe detetctor test <pathToAConfigFile> <pathToAnotherConfigFile> <pathToModelDef> -dont_show <pathToImage>
```

I tried multiple aproaches. I used Runtime.getRuntime().exec() like so.

```
try {

            String command = "darknet.exe detector test data\\obj.data cfg\\yolov4-obj.cfg backup\\rgbmodel\\yolov4-obj_last.weights -dont_show C:\\Users\\felix\\Desktop\\yoloTestSet\\RGBTest\\IMG_2392.jpg";
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait " + command, null,
                    new File("C:\\AI\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64"));
            
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);

            proc.waitFor();
            

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also tried:

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd",
                "/C",
                "start",
                "darknet.exe",
                "detector",
                "test",
                "data\\obj.data",
                "cfg\\yolov4-obj.cfg",
                "backup\\rgbmodel\\yolov4-obj_last.weights",
                "-dont_show",
                "-ext_output",
                "C:\\Users\\felix\\Desktop\\yoloTestSet\\RGBTest\\IMG_2392.jpg"
                
                );
        
        pb.directory(new File("C:\\AI\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64"));
        
        try {
            Process process  = pb.start();
             InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String output = null;
                while ((output = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }
         
                //wait for the process to complete
                //process.waitFor();
         
                //close the resources
                //bufferedReader.close();
                process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Both will run the process and print the desired output on cmd and closes the cmd afterwards. So far its just what i want. My problem now is, how can read this output properly.

```
br.readLine()
```

seems to be null.
If I leafe out the "start" before the actuall command, I can read the first line of the output, then everything gets stuck, leaving out "cmd" gives me this error:

```
Cannot run program "darknet.exe" (in directory "C:\AI\Yolo_v4\darknet\build\darknet\x64"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

The doku is a bit short on what the "cmd /C start" part actually does.
I would appreciate some advice on what is the issue here and how to do that properly,
regards Felix

Comment: Two things to think about -- 1)  The process that you're calling is cmd.exe, not darknet.exe.  This is adding additional complexity that you might not really need.  2) The docs indicate that a null response on `getInputStream()` occurs when something is redirecting your output (see #1)

Comment: The problem is, i dont really know how to run darknet.exe without starting cmd.exe first. If I dont use
```
cmd /c start
```
before the rest of the command it wont start. Regarding the output: I can see the desired output on the cmd that opens so where would this be redirected to? Or is the fact that the output is displayed on cmd a redirection by itself?

Comment: Have you tried reading `process.getErrorStream()` or setting `pb.redirectError()`? Maybe your process writes to stderr instead of stdout? What seems a bit fishy though is the fact that you see output in the console.
The error you see without `cmd` indicates that the `darknet.exe` cannot be found. Can you try passing the full path instead of just `darknet.exe`?

Comment: Thanks friend u indead gave the right answer. Some of the Output was in the ErrorStream, however that didnt fix it all, also leaving out "cmd /c start" and using full paths was necassery to get it all. Doing so raised an internal YOLO error, which could be fixed in the part of yolo it came from. I have exactly what what I need now. Ill post the Solution. Thanks again, I was struggeling with this for a week now.
Btw it appears to be working with Runtime.exec only, not processBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Daniel Junglas hint, I found this to be a solution.

```
try {
            
            

            String command = "C:\\AI\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64\\darknet.exe detector test C:\\AI\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64\\data\\obj.data C:\\AI\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64\\cfg\\yolov4-obj.cfg C:\\AI\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64\\backup\\rgbmodel\\yolov4-obj_last.weights -dont_show -ext_output C:\\Users\\felix\\Desktop\\yoloTestSet\\RGBTest\\IMG_2392.jpg";
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null,
                    new File("C:\\AI\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64"));
            
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
            
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);
                
                while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);

            proc.waitFor();
            

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Some of the desired output was inside the ErrorStream. Also you need full paths and do a minor change to YOLO itself, since there is an internal error raised. "cmd /c start" is not necassery.